# C# Error Handling for System.Xml in a Console App

Tags: c#, error-handling, unhandled-exception

I've inherited a C# console app and I'm not well-versed in writing error handling.  After several months of this app running nightly without any issue, it just started throwing the following error, daily, for the last 3 days:

```
 Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XmlException: An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 5, position 338.
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.HandleEntityReference(Boolean isInAttributeValue, EntityExpandType expandType, Int32& charRefEndPos)
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishPartialValue()
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.get_Value()
    at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
    at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
    at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
    at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
    at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri)
    at Data.Service.AssignmentService.<HandleMarkupActivityStep>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\Users\default\Source\Workspaces\Data\Data - Transfer\Data.Service\AssignmentService.cs:line 381
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Vital4Data.Service.AssignmentService.<ProcessSingleHtmlSource>d__17.MoveNext() in C:\Users\default\Source\Workspaces\Data\Data - Transfer\Data.Service\AssignmentService.cs:line 948
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1(Object state)
    at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
    at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
    at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
 Status changed to Failed
 Job failed due to exit code -532462766
```

Until I can have someone dig into the app to solve the issue, I just need the app to ignore this error, and continue without failing, for now.  How would I go about adding error handling to the code to accomplish this?  Is this a candidate for a try/catch block?  Or is a try/catch block what caught and threw this in the first place?  I'd appreciate any guidance so I can simply tell the program to ignore the error and continue executing.

Comment: Just add a try-catch with an empty catch clause.

Comment: *I just need the app to ignore this error, and continue without failing* is very naive and ignorant approach. Investigate why the XML is causing the code to trip over. Open up the Xml file in question *Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.XmlException: An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 5, position 338.* Lack of error handling is a recipe for disaster, use `XmlException` in the `catch` block to determine what it is instead of using the generic `Exception` which is a very bad code smell.

Comment: @t0mm13b I completely understand, but this is very temporary band-aid (literally 5 days at the most) until I have a full-time resource dedicated to this who can do exactly what you mention.

Answer (score 1):

Console apps are often used on scheduled jobs.
As ColinM said, You should implement a try-catch, but I'd also recomend to log your trace for further analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the information, and yes I absolutely plan to further analyze when I get my new resource in here next week.  Regarding implementing the try/catch, the code at line 381 is a case inside a switch statement - would I need to wrap the entire switch statement in the try/catch, or just this one case from line 381?

Comment: Since you said you inherited the app, I would wrap the whole function, not only the switch. You probably don't know how much of a "Pandora Box" this app can be, so I wouldn't take any risks at this moment.
And then when your new resource arrives, you better refactor your code.
Cheers!